# Checking if value changed for unique values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My excel looks like this:

```
datestamp       page                revision    
2020-02-10      www.google.com      43218     
2020-02-10      www.yahoo.com       44476           
2020-02-10      www.bing.com        42357       

2020-02-11      www.google.com      43218   
2020-02-11      www.google.com      43219     
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44477      
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44477   
2020-02-11      www.bing.com        42358   
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44478
```

I want to check if `revision` changes per `page` and add a `TRUE`, `FALSE` value so that the data would look like this:

```
datestamp       page                revision        changes
2020-02-10      www.google.com      43218           FALSE ( because it's the first value and there is nothing to compare it with )
2020-02-10      www.yahoo.com       44476           FALSE ( because it's the first value and there is nothing to compare it with )
2020-02-10      www.bing.com        42357           FALSE ( because it's the first value and there is nothing to compare it with )

2020-02-11      www.google.com      43218           FALSE ( because previous revision value for google.com is the same - 43218 )
2020-02-11      www.google.com      43219           TRUE ( because previous revision value for google.com is different - 43218, and now its 43219 )
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44477           TRUE ( because previous revision value for yahoo.com is different - 44476, and now its 44477 )
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44477           FALSE ( because previous revision value for yahoo.com is the same - 44477 )
2020-02-11      www.bing.com        42358           TRUE ( because previous revision value for bing.com is different - 42357, and now its 42358 )
2020-02-11      www.yahoo.com       44478           TRUE ( because previous revision value for yahoo.com is different - 44477, and now its 44478 )
```

How could I achieve this? Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `D2`, try the following:

```
=IF(C2<>"",IFERROR(LOOKUP(2,1/(B$1:B1=B2),C$1:C1)<>C2,FALSE),"")
```

Drag down.

**Note:** The initial `IF` is there to check for empty values as per your sample data. Scratch if there isn't any empty cells.

---

**Office 365 - Dynamic Array Formulas**

As per OP's comment, the above could return a `#SPILL!` error. As I personally do not have access to these functions the following is just an assumption and it would be great if someone could confirm:

***Taken from [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/implicit-intersection-operator-ce3be07b-0101-4450-a24e-c1c999be2b34):***

With the comming of dynamic array formulas implicit intersection is no longer at play at times. Since `LOOKUP` is throwing away *all* but one values in non-dynamic array formulas it no longer does so within dynamic array formulas. Excel now supports looking up multiple values and no longer does implicit intersection silently. If there isn't enough space to return the values to the grid you will see the #SPILL error. Therefor we need to escape that behaviour with an `@`:

```
=IFERROR(@LOOKUP(2,1/(B$1:B1=B2),C$1:C1)<>C2,FALSE)
```

In older versions (like mine) that `@` is accepted but silently removed since implicit intersection is allready in place.

Comment: I do not have empty cells, in the first row I am getting FALSE, in the header row, after that I am getting `#SPILL!` message for every cell. Do you have an idea what might cause this?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis, dit you insert the formula in `D2`, as per my answer? `#SPILL!` is an error that would occur when you have access to the dynamic array formulas within office 365. Not sure how to overcome that as I have no access. I'll read some information and post *what* could be an answer to that problem

Comment: Yes, if I drag one line down, D3 gets filled with FALSE and there is also FALSE in D3 in greyed out text. If I drag the formula from D2 to D4, D3 becomes `#SPILL!`, D4 is FALSE and D5 and D6 has FALSE in greyed out text.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis, please test the edited answer. I unfortunately wen by the documentation and placed the `@` operator (to invoke implicit intersection) in front of the `LOOKUP` function. It might be incorrect.

Comment: Thank you, it works, not sure on what depends but I had to replace `,` in your formula to `;`.

Comment: That is locale dependent =) @JonasPalačionis